# NetLogo: moving to a random patch with specified probabilities

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, to move a turtle to a random patch within a specific radius, e.g. radius 1,

```
move-to one-of patches in-radius 1
```

works. Suppose `patches in-radius 1` contains several patches and each patch has an attribute (e.g., x). I want the movement to follow a multinomial process. For example, when there are 5 possible patches (with x1, x2, x3, x4, x5), I want the probability that the turtle moves to ith patch to be x_i/(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5) (i=1..5). How do I accomplish this?

(Updated)
Alan and Bryan's responses helped a lot. Suppose `xxx` is an agentset that contains patches. How to I select the ith element of the agentset? If `xxx` is a list (and suppose if I want the 4th element)

```
position 4 xxx
```

seems to work. But for an agentset, it does not work.

Comment: See Bryan Head's `weighted-random` procedure here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068736/multi-nomial-logit-modelling-choice-netlogo

Comment: You will need to change `to` to `to-report`.

Comment: Woops, thanks Alan, I've corrected my answer to that question. quibble, you can also use the rnd extension for this: https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension

Comment: Thank you Alan and Bryan. It will work. After getting a random number from the procedure, corresponding the number to a specific patch is a bit of a problem especially when there are many patches (e.g., radius is long) [e.g., patch=45 is selected, but which one is it?], though.